# Why should I use @NaturalId?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, naturalid

When I am looking for `@NaturalId` and trying to understand what the advantages of using it is. I am reading several articles like [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-naturalid-business-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) article.

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(
    usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE
)
@NaturalIdCache
public class Post {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @NaturalId
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String slug;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
 
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        Post post = (Post) o;
        return Objects.equals(slug, post.slug);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(slug);
    }
}
```

And when retrieving record, the following approach is used:

```
String slug = "high-performance-java-persistence";
 
Post post = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)
    .bySimpleNaturalId(Post.class)
    .load(slug);
```

I am wondering that, what is I remove `@NaturalId` from the `slug` field and retrieve the record via `bySlug` method? As far as I see, `@NaturalId` acts as an index and may help to access the record faster I think. Is that true? Could you explain the benefits of it?

Comment: Why would you use unwrap in the first place

Comment: @Antonio See my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [Hibernate ORM documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#naturalid) explains the use of `@NaturalId` pretty well:

> Natural ids represent domain model unique identifiers that have a meaning in the real world too. Even if a natural id does not make a good primary key (surrogate keys being usually preferred), it’s still useful to tell Hibernate about it.

When you mark a field as natural id, Hibernate creates a unique constraint for it in the database (if you generate it at start up) and [caching using the field as key becomes possible](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#naturalid-mutability-caching). You can also use `@NaturalIdCache` to use the second-level cache. In general, it should lead to better performance when looking for the entity using the field.

Comment: **#1** Do we have to add @NaturalIdCache annotation whenever we use NaturalId ?

Comment: **#2** As far as I see, @NaturalId annotation is used an index, but I am not sure if I should use it whenever I have a unique field in my entity. Any idea?

Comment: **#3** Can I use @NaturalId when both; the property is updatable or not?

Comment: About number 3, yes, you can use NaturalId even when the property is mutable. [It is explained in the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#naturalid-mutability-caching).

Comment: WHat about other numbers?

Comment: If you know that the field must be unique, I think it makes sense to use it.  But it depends on your use case. It might not make any difference if you never query that field. Same for using the second level cache. It's up to you to measure the performance.

Comment: I guess having the index on the field might benefit all queries filtering using the field, so I don't see any particular disadvantage in using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Voted up and marked as answer.